# ffmpeg-python take input from x11grab

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am using FFmpeg-python bindings for using FFmpeg. I have to take input from x11grab, for which I already have an equivalent command in shell i.e,

`ffmpeg -nostdin -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel panic -video_size 1920x1080 -r 60 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :1 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p file.mkv &`

I have gone through docs of FFmpeg-Python to create an equivalent command, however, I could not find any example of x11grab in the documentation.

I wanted to use a binding to make the code more readable, the command works with subprocess.call() / os.system()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax resembles the following code sample:

```
import ffmpeg

(
    ffmpeg
    .output(ffmpeg.input(':0', s='192x128', r=30, f='x11grab'),
            ffmpeg.input('sine=frequency=500', f='lavfi'),
            'file.mkv',
            vcodec='libx264', acodec='aac', preset='fast', pix_fmt='yuv420p', t=5)
    .global_args('-nostdin', '-hide_banner', '-nostats')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
```

---

Notes:

- My Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual machine, was not accepting 1920x1080 resolution, and not accepting the audio input device (I replaced it with synthetic audio).
- You can probably replace `ffmpeg.input('sine=frequency=500', f='lavfi')` with:
  `ffmpeg.input('pulse', f='alsa', ac=2)`, but I can't test it...
- The example selects video and audio codecs: `vcodec='libx264', acodec='aac'` (selecting the codecs is a good practice).
- The example uses `t=5` for recording only 5 seconds.
- `.overwrite_output()` is used for overwriting the output without asking.

---

Grabbed sample:

[image]